# Seen a statement in c++ std::map<std::string, class setting, struct bases> s , what'd it be?

Tags: c++11, c++14

Seen a statement/expression in c++,

```
struct bases {
 int a;
 };

class setting {
int n;

};


  std::map<std::string, class setting, bases> s;

s["Please enter your keyword "] =  // .... so on
```

What's this supposed to mean in the best understandable explanation?

Comment: This is missing at least a semicolon after the first line. Even with that, it's hard to tell what exactly you want from us.

Comment: The current code is still invalid. It's missing semicolons after the class definitions, and `bases` does not provide a call operator that compares two `std::string` objects. It would be better if you kept your example as close as possible to the real code, otherwise a mistake in the code may lead to invalid answers.

Answer (score 1):

Check this documentation of [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). A map can be declared as below:

```
template
<
class Key,
class T,
class Compare = std::less<Key>,
class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> 
class map;
```

Which means map can contain a max of 4 template types: Key, Value, Compare type and an allocator type; of which the last 2 are optional.

Now your code:

```
std::map<std::string, class setting, bases> s
```

In this case `class setting` is the value and `struct bases` is the compare type. In plain english, `s` is a map which can mapp between `std::string` types and `class setting` while `struct bases` provides a way how the string keys will be compared for sorting the map elements.